# Value of a variable that will persist even after clearing cache in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching

In an iOS app I want to set a variable with some value, I need that value to persist even after the cache of that respective iPhone in which the App is being downloaded is deleted.

Example:
*NSString *val = @"Persist even after cache deletion";*

Need the value in string to persist even after cache wipe off/deletion from iPhone.

Comment: hat do u mean with "cache" in this case? a cache should contain only stuff that is re-creatable at any time. If you want to persist stuff even if an app is removed, this is not caching released.

Answer (score 5):

If we are talking of small bits of data, like user ids, you can store them in the keychain. it will persist even if the app is deleted.

Comment: @AVi, can you back your claim up. Because in my experience the data stays in the Keychain, even if all api of a vendor is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any way to store value after deleting application only way to upload value on your server and after reinstall download using like userId.

Comment: Not after application deletion, but after cache removal from phone settings.

Comment: Data saved in Keychain survives application deletion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at NSUserDefaults. This is a place whare you can store a small amount of data, that will persists between launches of your application.

Comment: Even after cache clearing/wipe off will that persist?

Comment: Yes indeed. That's the whole goal of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about cache clearing, `NSUserDefaults` will suffice. Values stored there will be lost if the application is deleted, though.

If you want your data to survive application deletion you can use the `Keychain`. This will allow you to save/retrieve data between uninstallation/reinstallation.

The `Keychain` approach is not device wipe proof, as this resets all data on the device. If however the user synced the keychain via `iCloud` and logs back in after wipe, then the keychain will be restored, and along with it your data.

Comment: So cache clearance won't affect value in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @AthulRaj, yes clearing cache affects only the cache folder, and `NSUserDefaults` is stored within that folder.

Answer (score -1):

If that was possible you would have a lot of garbage left on your device.

I'd suggest create user accounts and store the value in a database on a server. When the user deletes the app, the value stays in the DB and can be retrieved once the app is reinstalled.

Comment: well, it is possible for small and simple data.

Comment: and where wud that DB be stored exactly?

Comment: Actually, if the app is removed, the sandboxed data is gone, too.

Comment: I realise my answer was unclear. What I meant was to store the value on an online DB. That way the value can be retrieved after reinstall.